# Cancelling / Preventing route navigation in Dot Net Core

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I've a typical API in C# Dot Net Core, where a list of orders is returned back upon receiving the `ajax` request of `$.getJSON(apiUrl)` as below:

```
$.getJSON("api/Orders")
    .done(function (data) {
        // On success, 'data' contains a list of products.
        $.each(data, function (key, item) {
            // Add a list item for the product.
            $('<li>', { text: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($('#products'));
        });
    });
```

My controller is simply like below:

```
    public class OrdersController 
{
    [HttpGet("api/Orders")]
    public object Orders()
    { 
        return new
        {
            .
            .
        };
    }
}
```

The above is fine with me.

My problem is, if the user entered in the browser a url like: `http://localhost/api/Orders` he will be getting th same output, which I want to prevent.

i.e. I need to allow the access to my API through `ajax` only, and need to prevent (or cancel or redirect) it if received through `navigation` in the browser address line.

Thanks

Comment: You really cannot. If the browser is supposed to get the data, the browser must be able to get the data. Of course you can hinder it by playing with headers, like `accept` or something but it's still possible. Also looks a bit bad returning anonymous objects from an API rather than well defined objects.

Comment: No you can, just add some header to jquery request and create a middleware that sends 404 if header is not present.

Comment: how can I check the request header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the hits given, I solved it by the creating a `middleware` as below:

1. Created a folder `Middleware`
2. Inside this new folder, I created 2 files `MiddleWalewareExtensions.cs` and `RequestHeaderMiddleware.cs`
3. The `MiddleWalewareExtensions.cs` is the one defining all the middlewares we are having, in this example it is just one, the code is:

   ```
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;    // for IApplicationBuilder
   namespace myApp.Middleware
   {
      public static class MiddlewareExtensions  
   {
      public static IApplicationBuilder UseRequestHeaderMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
   {
       return builder.UseMiddleware<RequestHeaderMiddleware>();
   }
   ... here you can define others
   ```

   }
     }
4. The `RequestHeaderMiddleware` is the middleware that checks if url contains the word `api` it is executed only if the header contains `user-key` and this key is a valid one, otherwise an error is returned. 
   if the link does not contains the api word it is executed without a
   need of a user key.

   ```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace myApp.Middleware
    {
    public class RequestHeaderMiddleware  
    {
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    public RequestHeaderMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

   public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
   {
       string url = context.Request.Path;

       if (url.Contains("api") && !context.Request.Headers.Keys.Contains("user-key"))
       {
           context.Response.StatusCode = 400; //Bad Request                
           await context.Response.WriteAsync("You need a user key to be able to access this API..");
           return;
       }
       else
           {
               if(context.Request.Headers["user-key"] != "28236d8ec201df516d0f6472d516d72d")
               {
                   context.Response.StatusCode = 401; //UnAuthorized
                   await context.Response.WriteAsync("Invalid User Key");
                   return;
               }
           }

       await _next.Invoke(context);
      }
     }
    }
   ```

   5. In the `Startup.cs` file add `using myApp.Middleware;` then:

      ```
      public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) 
      {
         app.UseRequestHeaderMiddleware();
         app.UseMvc(routes =>
         {
          routes.MapRoute(
              name: "default",
              template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
         });
      ```
   6. In the JavaScript `client app` add the required header to the `xmlhttp` like:

      ```
         xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("user-key", "28236d8ec201df516d0f6472d516d72d");
      ```

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to disallow navigation requests whole-sale.

All you can really do is check for specific headers indicating that it's an AJAX request. Like X-Requested-With. But any basic http client will allow people to add it.

Comment: Better yet create middleware that will take care of this.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: You could create an actionfilter for your controller which inspects the request and returns a 403 or 404 if it can't find the x-requested-with header. Or like Stan said, create middleware.